# When building Kotlin code where functions have extremely long names, I get a "permission denied" error on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, kotlin, gradle, filenames, linux-mint

When I'm compiling Kotlin code and some functions have extremely long names, I get an error saying "Permission denied" on Linux Mint 20.3.

The culprits are usually tests that have been named like this:
``` fun ``This test fails when we get 500 from this external api but it should not really fail because this is a test with a really long name``() { // Test code } ```

The error I get then is this:
`

> Task :compileTestKotlin FAILED
> e: error while writing /home/dbrats/src/misc/my-repository/build/classes/kotlin/test/com/test/repo/MyClassTest$This test fails when we get 500 from this external api but it should not really fail because this is a test with a really long name$actualResponse$1.class (Permission denied)
> `

If I rename the function to something shorter (or clone the repo in /tmp/ so the path is shorter), it will build fine. So I figure it's related to some max path + filename length issues in my OS, but I can't figure out how to fix this without having to rename 50+ tests everytime I build someone's code (but I honestly think people should give their test functions shorter names than this...)

System:
Linux Mint 20.3
ext4

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you should not use such long names?

Comment: According to [here](https://www.linuxshelltips.com/find-limit-file-name-length-linux/), the max length of file names is 255 bytes, but `MyClassTest$This test fails when we get 500 from this external api but it should not really fail because this is a test with a really long name$actualResponse$1.class` is only 166 bytes. Is the actual name longer than this?

Comment: With the path I get 242 chars, still under 255 bytes if encoded in latin1 or UTF-8. That said, even just the filename of 166 chars blows the limit if encoded in UTF-16

Comment: The problem is that it also adds the path, so with the path + filename, the total is over 255 bytes.

Yeah, I agree that those names are too long, but I'm not the owner of the code, I simply need to manage to build it.

Answer (score 0):

In JUnit 5, there is [@DisplayName](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/DisplayName.html) annotation:

Example:

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Your very long test name from the api")
public void longTestName() {
    assertEquals(true, true);
}
```

Choose a shorter test name and add your long name in the @DisplayName annotation.